# Android studio emulator showing a big android screen

Tags: android

When I run my project on android studio the following is what's get shown: 
[image]

I am not sure why the mobile is showing so big and the screen is showing small.
What could be the reason for this?

Comment: try to create new AVD with different configurations. You may try exit from this emulator, build gradle, refresh your screen and start again also

Answer (score -1):

This is the bug with the latest android studio and usually happens on dual monitor setup, but after the update, it was resolved, for this,

### solution

1. stop the emulator
2. removes the frame
3. cold boot

> and don't create a custom device, use default one, e.g nexus or pixel

Hopefully, this will resolve the issue.